# CRON schedule for every x months

Tags: cron, expression, quartz-scheduler, recurrence

I need to list the upcoming commitments for a recurrent schedule. Say the commitment start on 1st Feb, 2015 and appear every 4 months, when user search for 2015 schedule, it should return 1st Feb, 1st Jun, 1st Oct. If schedule starts at 31st Dec 2014, and appear every 2 months, it should return 28th Feb, 30th Apr, 30th Jun, 31st Aug, 31st Oct, 31st Dec.

I tried with Quartz.net (or cronmaker.com), it yields different results. It is actually considering the base start as Jan 1st and calculating the rest of the result. For the CRON expression - "0 0 0 1 1/3 ? *", it returns the following results irrespective of start time.

1. Friday, May 1, 2015 12:00 AM
2. Tuesday, September 1, 2015 12:00 AM

Is there any additional setting required to get this working as require?

Comment: What should happen in February if the schedule starts on the 30th of Dec?  29th?, 28th?

Comment: I have covered the case in my question. it should return 28th Feb, 30th Apr, 30th Jun, 31st Aug,... (the last available date in the month)

Comment: ok, then what about Dec 27th? -- it's 4 days before the end of December... (hint: cron only counts forward)